# React / Node - PayPal can't capture a new subscription

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I wan't to capture a new paypal subscription from frontend in my backend and give response with the needed data for mongodb.

If I add a body with capture_type: 'OUTSTANDING_BALANCE' (I found that in the manual) I'm getting this error.
So I'm not sure either it's just a wrong body or i totally mess up something else in the backend but so far I can't capture the subscription even so I get a subscription Id from
createSubscription Controller

PayPalScriptProvider

```
<PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}>
    <PayPalSubscriptionButton/>
</PayPalScriptProvider>
```

PayPal Button

```
      {isPending ? <LoadingMedium /> : null}
      <PayPalButtons
        createSubscription={(data, actions) => {
          return axios
            .post(
              '/api/subscription',
            )
            .then((response) => {
              return response.data.id;
            });
        }}
        onApprove={(data, actions) => {
          axios
            .post(`/api/subscription/${data.subscriptionID}/capture`)
            .then(() => {
              axios
                .patch(
                  `/api/activesubscription`,
                  {
                    id: activeSub[0]?._id,
                    subscriptionID: data.subscriptionID,
                  }
                )
                });
            });
        }}
      />
```

Route for createSubscription

```
router.route('/subscription').post(async (req, res) => {
  const searchPlan = await SubscriptionAmount.find();
  console.log(searchPlan[0]?.subscriptionAmount);
  const subscription = await paypalFee.createSubscription(
    searchPlan[0]?.subscriptionAmount
  );
  res.json(subscription);
});
```

Router for onApprove

```
router.post('/subscription/:subscriptionID/capture', async (req, res) => {
  const { subscriptionID } = req.params;
  console.log('subscriptionID', subscriptionID);
  const captureData = await paypalFee.captureSubscription(subscriptionID);
  console.log('captureData', captureData);
  res.json(captureData);
});
```

createSubscription Controller

```
async function createSubscription(planId) {
  const accessToken = await generateAccessToken();
  const url = `${base}/v1/billing/subscriptions`;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      intent: 'subscription',
      plan_id: planId,
    }),
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log('data', data);
  return data;
}
```

captureSubscription Controller

```
async function captureSubscription(subscriptionId) {
  const accessToken = await generateAccessToken();
  const url = `${base}/v1/billing/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/capture`;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({
     // capture_type: 'OUTSTANDING_BALANCE',
    }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log('data', data);
  return data;
}
```

I'm getting this logs for my data in captureSubscription if I do not pass a body in my captureSubscription Controller:

```
captureData {
  name: 'INVALID_REQUEST',
  message: 'Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.',
  details: [
    {
      location: 'body',
      issue: 'MISSING_REQUEST_BODY',
      description: 'Request body is missing.'
    }
  ]
}
```

With body I'm getting this error

```
captureData {
  name: 'UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY',
  message: 'The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.',

  details: [
    {
      issue: 'ZERO_OUTSTANDING_BALANCE',
      description: 'Current outstanding balance should be greater than zero.'
    }
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ZERO_OUTSTANDING_BALANCE

There is no outstanding balance to capture. An outstanding balance occurs when payments are missed due to failures.

For ordinary (non-outstanding) subscription payments, no captures can be triggered. Subscriptions will capture automatically on the schedule you specify in the plan, that is the point of subscriptions.

Comment: Okay got it, but what should i use then for the body? Bcs it seems like I get this error when i leave the body:  issue: 'MISSING_REQUEST_BODY',

Comment: Nothing. For non-outstanding balances, there is no API capture step for subscriptions. You can listen for the webhook event PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED, which will arrive on its own. If you need to confirm server-side whether the subscription was /approved/ before hand, use a GET request to retrieve the status.